# Publishing pages cannot find /_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server

When trying to publish a page in sharepoint 2016 on premise the workflow doesn't start and instead an error occurs and looking at the uls log we see that it couldn't find /_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx. The virtual directory _layouts point to the physical 14 hive of sharepoint rather than physical 16 hive of sharepoint. How do we change this behavior?

Application error when access /_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.<>c__DisplayClass31.b__2e()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.GetGroupedPageUrls(String siteUrl, String pageUrl, String groupId)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.VariationEnumerable.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.AddDataItemsIntoItemsArray(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean useDataSource)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.PostGetDataAction(IEnumerable dataSource)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
 at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.IniWrkflIPPage.LoadFromWorkflowAssociation()
 at Microsoft.Office.Workflow.IniWrkflIPPage.OnLoad(EventArgs ea)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Should have said that this has happenned on a farm where the content databases have come from a sharepoint 2010 farm via sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There's no compatibility level available in 2016 . All sites are v15.Please [refer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/68547ab9-4c8f-423f-911f-ef926ad7a2e2/layouts-strategy-changed-again-in-sp2016?forum=SP2016)

Comment: Yes i realise that all sites are v15 but I was asking why our virtual directories were pointing to the physical 14 hive rather than our physical 16 hive.